# Excel VBA: Cleaning up code

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have written a basic excel code that loops through a range of cells and hides rows with the cell value of zero. The code works fine and I am not having any problems; However, the code feels lengthy and I was wondering if there was a way to shorten it or clean it up so it is easier to edit/follow in the future for new users.

I have posted the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.EnableEvents = False


If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J7")) Is Nothing Then


    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Filter"
            Worksheets("Filtered Data").Rows("7:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False

            Dim X As Range

            With Worksheets("Filtered Data")
                .Rows("7:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                If .Range("J7") = "Filter" Then
                    For Each X In .Range("J10:J503")
                        If X.Value = 0 Then
                            X.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        End If
                    Next X
                End If
            End With
        Case "Unfilter"
            Worksheets("Filtered Data").Rows("7:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case "-- Select --"
            Worksheets("Filtered Data").Rows("7:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select

Else

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I7")) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Filter"
                Worksheets("Filtered Data").Rows("7:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False

                Dim Y As Range

                With Worksheets("Filtered Data")
                    .Rows("7:600").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    If .Range("I7") = "Filter" Then
                        For Each Y In .Range("I10:I503")
                            If Y.Value = 0 Then
                                Y.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                            End If
                        Next Y
                    End If
                End With
            Case "Unfilter"
                Worksheets("Filtered Data").Rows("7:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "-- Select --"
                Worksheets("Filtered Data").Rows("7:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is off-topic. Insteac check out [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ok thank you for the advice

Comment: Is this Worksheet_Change on the Worksheets("Filtered Data")'s private code sheet or another worksheet's private code sheet?

Comment: Is the X.Value = 0 to include blank cells and cells that contain zero-length strings?

Comment: it is "filtered data"' private code and no it is to only hide cells with the value zero all blank or zero-length string cells remain unhidden

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user has a choice of three text values in either I7 or J7. It is likely that these two cells contain data validation lists or something similar since it doesn't seem very practical to have them type the values in manually every time a filtering operation is turned on or off.

I was inspired by your choice of worksheet names and went with an .AutoFilter method. I've assumed that this is all within the Worksheets("Filtered Data")'s private code sheet and that your I7:J7 options are not on another worksheet.

While it is certainly possible to change both I7 and J7 in a single operation like a paste, I've cut the operation down to only one column filtering at a time. This seems to reflect what I gathered from your original code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I7:J7")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        Set t = Intersect(Target, Range("I7:J7")).Cells(1)
        With Intersect(Columns(t.Column), Cells(7, t.Column).Resize(99999, 1), Me.UsedRange)
            If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

            If LCase(t.Value2) = "filter" Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0", Criteria2:="<>", _
                            Operator:=xlAnd, VisibleDropDown:=False
            End If
        End With
        Range("J7").Offset(0, Int(t.Column = Range("J7").Column)) = "'-- Select --"
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```